# SQL - update table with sequential numbering

Tags: mysql

i have a table in my MySQL database which i have added a new column to.

I would like to update this column on every row with a number starting at 20000 going up +1 each time.

i have tried this solution:

```
UPDATE table1 set new_col = new_col + 1;
```

but it just updates all rows with the same number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this query to solve this:

```
SET @rank:=20000;
update customer
set accountnumber_new=@rank:=@rank+1
```

Comment: SET @rank:=19999; Then starts with 20000

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
UPDATE table1 t, (SELECT @nr:= 20000-1) tmp
   SET t.new_col = (@nr:=@nr+1) ;
```